# Is there any Open Source Utility to allow Amazon Echo controls of RPi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to use my Amazon Echo to control my Raspberry Pi.

Are there any Open Source Utilities available that will provide similar functionality as wemo or wink, but on the rPi?

Answer (score 0):

There are many projects for the rPi that allow functionality like Wemo or Wink would provide, but the Amazon Echo API is fairly new to the world, and as far as I am away, has not be used yet to take advantage of any rPi projects. That is not to say it is impossible.

If this functionality is something you need, I would recommend finding a rPi project that has most everything you are looking for and consult with the active community around that project about adding in such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same question, but specifically, we need an open source software module that has the abilities to connect to Echo in the same wifi environment (as a home device), and execute scripts in Linux environment (RPi).

So far I have found [this link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hacking-the-Amazon-Echo/) and I was able to connect

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the OP wants to pass Echo intents directly to a Pi, and trigger actions based on intents:

There are two considerations here:

1. **Network Connectivity:**

At the moment, Amazon Echo supports pointing a skill to AWS Lambda or any other *publicly* reachable https endpoint. If your Pi is behind a home router then it cannot accept intents from Echo.

Note: *You can setup port forwarding on your home router to forward all https requests to your Pi. This is easy to setup and demo but difficult to maintain and operate due to lack of static public IP for most home internet connections and security concerns of allowing traffic in.*

2. **Complexity of handling intents on the Pi:**
   Receiving and processing requests from an Echo is not entirely straight forward. I have found that using Lambda functions is the easiest and most reliable way. It is also easier to troubleshoot Lambda functions using CloudFront logs.

Note: *There are Alexa Skills SDKs that does help to a large extent, but I still find them to be more tedious that using Lambda. YMMV*

I have a stable, working setup of my Pi controlled by Amazon Echo. And this is how it is configured:

1. Setup AWS Lambda to handle incoming intents from Echo
2. On Lambda, map a "ACTION KEYWORD" for each intent/slot
3. On a matching intent/slot, post the ACTION KEYWORD to PubNub channel
4. Setup my Pi to SUBSCRIBE to PubNub channel for new messages
5. If Pi receives a matching ACTION KEYWORD on the channel, it triggers a function/script
6. This function/script in turn has the complete execution logic (example: Open garage door)